# How to change dynamic feature module to normal module? (Please remove 'multiDexEnabled true|false' from your build.gradle file.`)

Tags: android

I am getting an error: `Native multidex is always used for dynamic features. Please remove 'multiDexEnabled true|false' from your build.gradle file.`

I have removed all the references of dynamic feature modules and flipped the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to solve this simple issue... I fixed it by removing the `com.android.dynamic-feature` plugin import from the module's build.gradle. You'll need `id 'com.android.library'` instead:

For example,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' <- ADD THIS
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature' <- REMOVE THIS
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```